# How can I use complex property names in anonymous type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, post, anonymous-types

In my MVC3 application I want to create an anonymous collection with fields names like this:

```
new 
{                                                                            
   Buyer.Firstname = "Jim",
   Buyer.Lastname = "Carrey",
   Phone = "403-222-6487",
   PhoneExtension = "",
   SmsNumber = "",
   Buyer.Company = "Company 10025",
   Buyer.ZipCode = "90210",
   Buyer.City = "Beverly Hills",
   Buyer.State = "CA",
   Buyer.Address1 = "Address 10025"
   Licenses[0].IsDeleted = "False",
   Licenses[0].ID = "6",
   Licenses[0].AdmissionDate = "2,1999",
   Licenses[0].AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "2",                                                                           

                                                                    }
```

I want to have this in order to send custom post requests during integration testing of my app. How can I declare a an anonymous collection with this field names?

Comment: Use nested anonymous types. Periods are not allowed in any property name. Unless you wanted to convert it to a dictionary...

Comment: I would also note it's **very encouraged** you create an explicit view model for this instead of using anonymous types. Maintaining code with anonymous types is going to be difficult in the future.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't `Phone`, `PhoneExtension`, and `SmsNumber` properties of `Buyer`? Isn't the whole object a `Buyer`?

Comment: Probably Buyer is a person, while Phone belongs to the company.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an anonymous collection of anonymous objects, like so:

```
Licenses = new [] {
    new {
        IsDeleted = "False",
        ID = "6",
        AdmissionDate = "2,1999",
        AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "2"
    } //, ... and so on
}
```

... and in context: *([edit] Oh, and I didn't see your buyer...)*

```
new 
{    
    Buyer = new {
        Firstname = "Jim",
        Lastname = "Carrey",
        Company = "Company 10025",
        ZipCode = "90210",
        City = "Beverly Hills",
        State = "CA",
        Address1 = "Address 10025",
    },                                                                        
    Phone = "403-222-6487",
    PhoneExtension = "",
    SmsNumber = "",
    Licenses = new [] {
        new {
            IsDeleted = "False",
            ID = "6",
            AdmissionDate = "2,1999",
            AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to wrap the above with `new { ... }` to make it clearer

Comment: this helps, but I still got an empty collection of licenses when binding collection on server. But I feel that I'm on right way. Thanks!

Comment: Probably this happens because anonymous list can't be serialized

Answer (score 6):

You could use object and collection initializer syntax:

```
var anonymousObject = new 
{                                                                            
    Phone = "403-222-6487",
    PhoneExtension = "",
    SmsNumber = "",
    Buyer = new 
    {
        Firstname = "Jim",
        Lastname = "Carrey",
        Company = "Company 10025",
        ZipCode = "90210",
        City = "Beverly Hills",
        State = "CA",
        Address1 = "Address 10025"
    },
    Licenses = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            IsDeleted = "False",
            ID = "6",
            AdmissionDate = "2,1999",
            AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "2",                                                                           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Apart from him beating you by 3.5 minutes... ;)

Comment: @canon: It can happen that an answer is published while you are still working on yours in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var x = new {
    Phone = "403-222-6487",
    PhoneExtension = "",
    SmsNumber = "",
    Buyer = new {
        Firstname = "Jim",
        Lastname = "Carrey",
        Company = "Company 10025",
        ZipCode = "90210",
        City = "Beverly Hills",
        State = "CA",
        Address1 = "Address 10025"
    },
    Licenses = new[] {
        new {
            IsDeleted = "False",
            ID = "6",
            AdmissionDate = "2,1999",
            AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "2"},
        new {
            IsDeleted = "True",
            ID = "7",
            AdmissionDate = "17,2001",
            AdmissionDate_monthSelected = "3"}
    }
};
```

Note: I am using a nested anonymous type for buyers and a nested array of yet another anyonymous type for licences. This allows you to access values like this

```
string name = x.Buyer.Lastname;
string id = x.Licences[0].ID;
```